# Why won't my rvm allow me to switch to an alternative Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rvm

Ubuntu already has Ruby 1.8.7 installed. Then I installed rvm and used it to install Ruby 1.9.2, which is the version I want to use. However, ruby -v always returns 1.8.7.

How do I get rvm to use Ruby 1.9.2?

```
bxu@vm-bxu:~$ rvm use 1.9.2
Using /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320
bxu@vm-bxu:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: Your question and title seem to be asking completely different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the terminal:

```
rvm use 1.9.2
```

Comment: Without the --default flag, the user will need to do that each time.

Answer (score 3):

#### The Problem

RVM does its own installation magic, but in Ubuntu's case it doesn't always install to the right Bash startup file. You probably don't actually have RVM running properly; even though it's sort of installed.

#### The Fix

You need to make sure the following two lines are at the BOTTOM of your ~/.bashrc file.

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin
```

Then restart your terminal emulator or log back in. Note that sourcing ~/.bashrc has been known *not* to work in some cases, so this step will save your sanity.

RVM should now be working properly. The last step is to set your default Ruby.

```
rvm --default use 1.9.2
```

#### Important Edit

As I've just been reminded, RVM breaks Ubuntu login shells by installing ~/.bash_login, which overrides your Ubuntu ~/.profile in login shells. Move the code over to your ~/.bashrc if you haven't already done so, then remove or rename ~/.bash_login.

Answer (score -1):

on Ubuntu you need to enable login shell in your terminal emulator, we have a quite good documentation for this at rvm site:
https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/

Comment: RVM insists on creating ~/.bash_login during its installation. Ubuntu 11.x doesn't use that file by default (it uses ~/.profile), so this advice just perpetuates the problem.

Comment: loading rvm in ~/.profile is problematic because it is loaded just on beginning of user login and rvm + its default will be set for the whole session, so changing default ruby will not work