# Rails installation isn't permanent on Ubuntu Bash for Windows 10, how can I fix this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, windows-10

I recently started testing out the Ubuntu bash for Windows 10 sub-system for my Ruby and Rails work. To set up rails, I followed [this guide](https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10) from GoRails.com.

Everything worked yesterday. But after shutting down my PC and starting up the Ubuntu bash terminal again today, it doesn't seem to recognize ruby or rails anymore. i.e. typing `ruby -v` gives me this:

`The program 'ruby' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install ruby`

Typing `rails -v` gives me:

`bash: /mnt/c/Ruby22-x64/bin/rails: ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

For reference, I used the instructions from the above guide to install Ruby 2.4.0 using RVM and Rails 5.1.1. When I ran `ruby -v` and `rails -v` yesterday, everything worked fine.

I should note, that before testing out the Ubuntu sub-system, I've been using Ruby and Rails on Windows itself - In this case, I have Ruby 2.2.5 (64-bit) installed using an installer downloaded from [here](https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/). I installed Rails on Windows by running `gem install rails` on the Windows command prompt.

I am on Windows 10 Home Version 1703 (OS Build 15063.483)

Comment: You probably need to do the `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` line from the guide each time you open a new shell, unless you add that your shell's initialization file.

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you so much! If you could put it as an answer I can mark it as the best answer!

Comment: For reference, @jordanm if it helps your answer, I also used the code `echo "source \$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164765/using-rvm-on-ubuntu-12-04-to-use-rails-the-program-rails-is-currently-not-ins?rq=1) to make this command happen automatically when running the bash terminal :)

Answer (score 0):

from your story above, probably how you start the terminal (command prompt)

if you run using go rails make sure your run the terminal with bash, press start, then search for bash then you click bash icon

if you using ruby from ruby installer / [rails installer](http://railsinstaller.org/en) you search "command prompt with ruby and rails" and click the icon

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But turns out it was that I needed to run an RVM command before using ruby (See the comment on the question). Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly install ruby using rvm manager. It enables you to switch between different ruby versions as per your project.
Follow the instructions on this website:

http://rvm.io/rvm/install

and install ruby through rvm.
For the problem of unable to detect ruby on your system change settings for your terminal through Edit->preferences/profile preferences -> command ->(tick mark) run command as login shell.

Comment: Unfortunately, these aren't available on the Ubuntu bash for Windows 10 :(

Turns out it was that I needed to run an RVM command before using ruby (See the comment on my question above). Thanks anyway!